# Microsoft PXT/Makecode: Field editors

Tags: javascript, makecode

i have a question regarding field editors in Makecode:

So here is a part of the documentation:

> Field editors let you control how a parameter value is entered or selected. A field editor is a shadow block that invokes the render of a selection UI element, dropdown list of items, or some other extended input method.
> A field editor is attached to a parameter using the shadow attribute with the field editor name.

Then they use the following example:

```
/**
* Toggle the LED on or off
*/
//% block="LED $on"
//% on.shadow="toggleOnOff"
export function ledOn(on: boolean) {

}
```

This makes totally sense. But then if i want to use the field editor "note" (see [this link](https://makecode.com/playground#field-editors-note)) and use `variable.shadow="note"` it does not work, i need to use `variable.fieldEditor="note"`.

But with other field editors, like "colorNumberPicker" the `shadow`-keyword works fine.

Does anyone know why?

Already described above.